# AngularJS template loading late. Directive not able to find the elements

Tags: angularjs, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I'm working on preparing a .net based AngularJS web application for modern tooling(get rid of nuget in favor of npm, bundling with webpack, etc.) and later on re-writing it to Angular.

I'm having an issue with the bundled version where a directive is trying to bind a click events to a template anchor tag (< a >) but the template is not yet loaded.

On the old version with many < script > tags for every JS file this is not happening. *The directive is first* on the order and the controller of the template(which is loaded inside a **ng-include** and uses the directive) *comes after*.

On the bundled version I simply changed the .js files to .ts, added the npm dependencies, the needed imports statements on each file and in the webpack entry I kept the same order as in the old index.html. Still, when de directive code runs the elements it searches for are not there yet.

The parts affected: (already updated with @bryan60 answer suggestion)

shell.html

```
...
<div data-ng-if="vm.showMenuBar" data-ng-include="'/app/layout/sidebar.html'" class="fader-animation"></div>
...
```

shell.ts

```
import angular from 'angular';

const sideBarTemplate = require('./sidebar.html')

let controllerId = "shell";
angular.module("eqc").controller(controllerId, ["$rootScope", "$templateCache", "$window", "authService", "common", "config", shell]);

function shell($rootScope, $templateCache, $window, authService, common, config) {

    $templateCache.put('app/layout/sidebar.html', sideBarTemplate)
```

sidebar.html

```
<div data-cc-sidebar data-ng-controller="sidebar as vm">
<div class="sidebar-filler"></div>
<div class="sidebar-dropdown"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
<div class="sidebar-inner">
    <div class="sidebar-widget"></div>
    <ul class="navi">
        <li class="nlightblue fade-selection-animation" data-ng-class="vm.isCurrent(r)" data-ng-repeat="r in vm.navRoutes">
            <a href="{{r.url}}" data-ng-bind-html="r.config.settings.content"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

cc-sidebar directive:

```
app.directive('ccSidebar', function () {
    // Opens and clsoes the sidebar menu.
    // Usage:
    //  <div data-cc-sidebar>
    // Creates:
    //  <div data-cc-sidebar class="sidebar">
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };
    return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var $sidebarInner = element.find('.sidebar-inner');
    var $dropdownElement = element.find('.sidebar-dropdown a');
    element.addClass('sidebar');
    $dropdownElement.click(dropdown); // <--- Here's the problem. 'dropdown' function is omitted but its defined in the next line
                                      // The error on the console is: TypeError: "$dropdownElement.click is not a function"
                                      // That's because it is never found
```

main.ts

```
import "./eqc";
import "./config"
import "./config.exceptionHandler"
import "./config.route"
//All folders bellow have index.ts in them including their .ts files
import "./common"
import "./services"
import "./Views"
import "./layout"
```

eqc.ts

```
import 'jquery';
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-animate';
import 'angular-route';
import 'angular-sanitize';
import 'angular-messages';
import 'angular-local-storage'
import 'angular-ui-bootstrap';
import 'angular-ui-mask';
import 'angular-loading-bar';
import 'breeze-client';
import 'breeze-client/breeze.bridge.angular';

let eqc = angular.module("eqc", [ .....
```

webpack.config.ts

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/app/main.ts",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            //All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: { loader: "ts-loader" }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: { loader: 'html-loader' }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        //Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as a resovaable extension
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    devtool: "source-map"
};
```

My folder structure:
[image]

Comment: you should probably show the directive config and template causing problems rather than describe it... ng-include is fine IF you've actually included your template files in your bundle correctly. so your template code and webpack config matters here too.. though generally I'd recommend using the template cache and requiring your templates and let webpack inline them

Comment: updated the question with my code.

Comment: and what's the specific error, also, the shell directive config? I'm a little confused about  your code because you seem to be using ng-include for the template, but the template also has a directive? I'm not sure why you'd configure that way or how the directive is linked to the template

Comment: Fixed the missing code parts.
Yes, the cc-sidebar directive is used inside the sidebar.html template, that is then inserted in the ng-include on shell.html

Comment: which angularjs version is this? why'd you choose to like, sort of cobble this directive together using various disconnected directives instead of setting the template and controller in the directive declaration or using a component?

Comment: Its v1.7.9. This whole app organization was done by someone else in plain js. I'm just beginning to upgrade it. First making it modern-tooling ready, then rewrite it to Angular.
The only issue I had was this one, rest is working just fine.
This directive bind a click event to the Menu anchor (only visible in mobile devices) so that it slides down a menu.

Comment: tbh I'd just rewrite this as component and see if it fixes whatever is going on here. You'll need to do a lot of that kind of stuff before starting a migration anyway as this will not translate well in a migration effort

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what your problem is due to the lack of code / details... but very generally, the simplest way to make ng-include work with webpack is to use require statements and the template cache....

Assuming you have some template like:

```
<ng-include src="'app/my-included-template.html'"></ng-include>
```

in the controller for that template, you'll have something set up like...

```
const myIncludedTemplate = require('./my-included-template.html')

function MyController($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('app/my-included-template.html', myIncludedTemplate)
}
```

to make the require statement work with webpack, you'll need am html loader configured, i have this to do it in my module rules array...

```
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      'html-loader'
    ],
  },
```

this particular implementation will require you to `npm install --save-dev html-loader`

this will instruct webpack to inline your template to the source file, and then your controller will immediately put it into the template cache so that it can be loaded correctly without worrying about the webpack bundle structure itself as angular will check the template cache before loading remotely. This is also a generally more performant way of doing things.

you can also do something similar when defining your directive / component templates:

```
template: require('./my-directive-template.html'),
```

which yields the same benefits of webpack just inlining the template so it doesn't need to be loaded remotely.

Comment: Hi brigan60, thanks for the reply. I updated my code with your suggestion but the same error still popping. I updated my question with the code already with your suggestion. Hopefully its easier now to see what I'm doing wrong.